# What's the proper REST API url for updating sub-resources?

Tags: rest, api

It seems to be a good practice to follow this rule:

> If a resource is related to another resource use subresources.

Example:

> GET /users/711/posts ====> Returns a list of posts for user 711
>   GET /users/711/posts/4 ====> Returns post #4 for user 711

Now what if I want to update a sub-resource? Should I still use this relation? Which of the following two approaches is more preferred/standard?

> PUT /users/711/posts/4 =====> Update post #4
>   PUT /posts/4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep it consistent.

`/users/711/posts/4` is a URI that identifies/locates a resource in your server. The same identifier/locator should be used to get a representation, delete and replace the state of the resource.